# Eclipse RCP Extension Points

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, rcp, e4

Hey guys it has been a couple of week that I started developing stuff based on RCP and frankly speaking i'm facing several problems since i haven't found so much online then the concepts behind RCP programming (at least for me) are not such linear.

First of all let me say that I'm using the E4 framework (Application Model) and I want to populate two parts (UI Parts) where their definitions are basically defined in an external plug-in.

For instance:
- Part1 (defined in Application e4) implements Class1(defined in a Plug-in called ExtPlugin).
- Part2 (defined in Application e4) implements Class2(defined in a Plug-in called ExtPlugin).

How should I work this out using extension points and extension?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of your plugins can use an application model fragment.e4xmi to declare your Part and the class.

Use the `org.eclipse.e4.workbench.model` extension point to tell e4 about the fragment.

If you use 'File > New > Other... > Eclipse 4 > Model > New Model Fragment' this will create the fragment.e4xmi file and the plugin.xml extension point.

In the fragment.e4xml you create a 'Model Fragment'. In this fragment the 'Element ID' is the id of something you are extending - for parts this will often be the id of a Part Stack defined in the Application.e4xmi. The 'feature name' will often be 'children'. Add your Part to the Model Fragment.

More [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4Modularity/article.html)

Comment: Well, basically as far as I have understood for UI elements (like parts) it's better to rely on fragments rather than defining an Interface and implement an "@Override Class" for that Interface: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseExtensionPoint/article.html.

Comment: '@Override' has nothing to do with part definitions.

Comment: I was referring to the step where the greet() method was "overridden" to implement its German version(see the tutorial). By the way using model fragment should provide enough "modularity" to my code right?